# Combinatorics story

Tags: combinatorics

A snail moves every minute one centimeter north or one centimeter south. The snail moves exactly 20 minutes. In how many ways can the snail reach exactly 10 centimeters north to its starting
location after 20 minutes?

How do you approach such problem?

Comment: Answer for yourself, how many of the minutes did the snail travel north instead of south in order to have arrived at that final location.  Then, knowing that, answer how many sequences of that many norths and the appropriate number of souths exist... Binomial coefficients will be useful here.

Comment: Let $N,S$ be the number of steps taken north and south respectively. Then $N+S=20$ and $N-S=10$. This  implies the number of north and south steps is fixed. Now count all the possible ways of doing so, since the order of steps is immaterial.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First write down the conditions in more mathy language: you know $n+s = 20$ and $n-s=10$ where $n$ is the number of steps north and $s$ is the number of steps south.

Second note that this has a unique solution, ie. the number of steps north is fixed, no matter which path you take.

Third find out how many ways there are to distribute the fixed amount of norths over twenty steps.

Comment: So, do we need to choose 10 out of 20 steps?

Comment: I think it should be 15 out of 20..

Comment: Can you explain why?

Comment: Because that is the solution of $n$ in the system of equations above. Intuitively: we need to go 10 steps north and every further step has to be paired with a step in the reverse direction to „stay“ at 10 steps north. So out of the remaining 10 steps we ought to go 5 north and 5 south, which makes 15 steps overall.